# Why doesn't an NSManagedObject relationship object load properly unless I first access the description of the parent class?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I am loading a list of objects from CoreData like this:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)loadAllPoisFromCache:(BOOL)includeCustom {  
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

[request setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"PointOfInterest" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                          initWithKey:@"sortOrder" ascending:YES];
[request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
[sort release];

if(!includeCustom) {
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(custom == %i)",NO];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];
}

[request setEntity:entity];
NSError *error = nil;
NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];

[request release];

return mutableFetchResults;
}
```

The "PointOfInterest" entity is a COMPPointOfInterest and it has a relationship to an entity "Location" which is a COMPLocationEntity.

I then loop through the results:

```
NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [self loadAllPoisFromCache:YES];

if (mutableFetchResults != nil && [mutableFetchResults count] > 0) {

    NSLog(@"NOTIF_PoisLoaded with data from cache");

    for (COMPPointOfInterest *aPoi in mutableFetchResults) {
        COMPLocationEntity *locBeforePrintingOutPoi = aPoi.locationEntity;
        NSLog(@"Loc class before printing out parent POI = %@", [locBeforePrintingOutPoi class]);
        NSLog(@"Loaded POI %@ from cache %@ and location %@", aPoi.poiId, [aPoi class], [locBeforePrintingOutPoi class]);
        NSLog(@"Loaded POI from cache %@", aPoi);
        COMPLocationEntity *locAfterPrintingOutPoi = aPoi.locationEntity;   
        NSLog(@"Loc class refetched from parent POI after printing out POI = %@", [locAfterPrintingOutPoi class]);
        NSNumber *lat2 = locAfterPrintingOutPoi.latitude;
        NSLog(@"Lat from refetched loc %@", lat2);
        // crash on next line!
        NSNumber *lat = locBeforePrintingOutPoi.latitude;
        NSLog(@"Lat %@", lat);

    }
```

Now, this is where I'm stuck, if you run this, the output is as follows:

> 2011-01-24 16:35:41.063 NEC Companion[11959:207] NOTIF_PoisLoaded with data from cache
>
> 2011-01-24 16:35:41.064 NEC Companion[11959:207] Loc class before printing out parent POI = _NSObjectID_48_1
>
> 2011-01-24 16:35:41.068 NEC Companion[11959:207] Loaded POI 1 from cache COMPPointOfInterest and location _NSObjectID_48_1
>
> 2011-01-24 16:35:41.069 NEC Companion[11959:207] Loaded POI from cache  (entity: PointOfInterest; id: 0xae19110  ; data: {
>       cacheDate = "2011-01-24 16:09:26 +0000";
>       custom = 0;
>       locationEntity = "0xae18ff0 ";
>       logoUrl = "http://192.168.37.213/companion/images/mapicons/es";
>       poiId = 1;
>       sortOrder = 0;
>   })
>
> 2011-01-24 16:35:41.071 NEC Companion[11959:207] Loc class refetched from parent POI after printing out POI = COMPLocationEntity
>
> 2011-01-24 16:35:41.072 NEC Companion[11959:207] Lat from refetched loc 52.460118
>
> 2011-01-24 16:35:41.072 NEC Companion[11959:207] -[_NSObjectID_48_1 latitude]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xae18ff0

The crux of my problem is that if I grab the "locationEntity" attribute from the POI immediately when I start iterating through the list, the class comes out as _NSObjectID_48_1, I then do an NSLog(@"Loaded POI from cache %@", aPoi); and following that I get the "locationEntity" attribute again and I end up with the correct COMPLocationEntity class!

So it looks like calling the description method is doing something to fully instantiate the POI correctly...but what?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, looks like I've solved it. My problem was indeed that the locationEntity was a relationship and adding the following to my query causes the object to load correctly with my location relationship fully populated.

> [request setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching:
>       [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"locationEntity"]];

See http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/NSFetchRequest.html

Comment: Hi Kiera, I am also facing the same issue. can you please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29010721/core-data-getting-nsobjectid-48-1-username-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-ins and provide me your valuable feedback.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's faulting - CoreData isn't getting the data until you ask for it specifically.

You have specified not to fault the properties of each aPoi in your results when you created your fetch request. This means that it's got all the properties of the COMPointOfInterest object.

However, this doesn't mean that all it's relationship's objects are not faulted - your COMPLocationEntity objects are (I assume) a relationship. CoreData won't get these until they are specifically asked for and will mark them as faults until then. Hence getting a very odd object name. When you ask for a COMPLocationEntity's property (in this case the description*), the fault fires and the real COMPLocationEntity object is loaded.

The fault is fired in this line :

```
NSLog(@"Loaded POI from cache %@", aPoi);
```

Core Data needs some real data to output your aPoi object so goes and gets it from the database and makes the COMPLocationEntity object.

Hope that helps.

*Usually, calling description on a NSManagedObject **won't** cause a fault (it's done that way deliberately). Have you overridden the description method in your class to output something more useful? If so, you're causing the fault to be triggered yourself!

Comment: Hi Dean, thanks for your quick reply. I can see that doing the NSLog on the POI will cause everything to load up, but I don't know what the proper solution is to get this to work. I want to be able to just do:
 aPoi.locationEntity.latitude
But doing that just blows up because the relationship object is not fully loading. How can I force it to really fetch the relationship without having to print the whole thing out (which is clearly a complete hack :)?

Comment: Oh, that shouldn't break at all - that should be enough to cause it to fetch the data :( Can you add the stack trace to your question so we can see what error you're getting?