# Core Data getting [_NSObjectID_48_1 userName]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

A->>B

I have two entities A&B and each are related as one to many relationship.  I am trying to access specific B attribute value and all A entity attributes by grouping. However I am getting error as `[_NSObjectID_48_1 userName]`: unrecognized selector sent to instance when I try to access relationship object of B(that is a).

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[SamCoreDataHelper sharedInstance] managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *fr = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"B"];
    NSError *error;
    NSExpressionDescription *total = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
    [total setExpression:[NSExpression expressionWithFormat:@"@sum.marks"]];
    [total setName:@"total"];
    [total setExpressionResultType:NSDecimalAttributeType];


    [fr setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"subject",@"a", total, nil]];
    [fr setPropertiesToGroupBy:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"subject", @"a", nil]];
    [fr setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"a"]];
    fr.returnsObjectsAsFaults = NO;
    [fr setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType ];

    NSArray *resultArray = [context executeFetchRequest:fr error:&error];

for (NSDictionary *result in resultArray) {
        NSNumber *total = [result valueForKey:@"total"];
        NSString *subject = [result valueForKey:@"subject"];
        A *a = [result objectForKey:@"a"];
        NSLog(@"%@", a.useName);// Here I am getting error as **[_NSObjectID_48_1 userName]: unrecognized selector sent to instance**
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will receive "object id" instead of instance of `NSManagedObject` for the relative object when the result of `NSFetchRequest` is set to `NSDictionaryResultType`.

So you need to fetch it "by object id":

```
A * a = (A*)[ managedObjectContext objectWithID:[result valueForKey:@"a"]];
NSLog("%@",a.userName );
```

**UPD:**

```
fr.returnsObjectsAsFaults = NO;
```

is useless here because the return type is `NSDictionaryResultType`.

Comment: It works Sim. Thanks a lot.  I have been crushing my mind for past 2hour.

Comment: @Nandha you're welcome,  I prefer to make "group by" on a simple props, so the results can be used without extra work. In your case I would use 'a.userName' in setPropertiesToFetch instead of 'a'. If I need more data from 'a' I would just put it there in a similar form.

Answer (score -1):

How about using the following for iteration..

```
for (A *a in resultArray) {
        NSLog(@"%@", a.useName); 
}
```

Comment: Here result type is NSDictionaryResultType, so we can access A object directly.